# JS | Switch Statement | How to create a password

Tags: javascript

The code below does not seem to be good enough for the following challenge:
Having got the value of the weekly password stored in weeklyPass, update the value of currentPass depending on the day of the week we are in. To know which day of the week it is simply access weekDay.
Remember that updating the password is appending the letters corresponding to the consonants present in the name of the current day of the week.
There are many ways of cracking this problem, but Elliot and the guys specifically asked for you to use a switch statement…

```
var weeklyPass = "darlene";
var weekDay = "monday";
var currentPass;

switch (weekDay) {
  case "monday":
    console.log(weeklyPass + "mnd");
    break;

  case "tuesday":
    console.log(weeklyPass + "tsd");
    break;

  case "wednesday":
    console.log(weeklyPass + "wsdnsd");
    break;

  case "thursday":
    console.log(weeklyPass + "thrsd");
    break;

  case "friday":
    console.log(weeklyPass + "frd");
    break;

  case "saturday":
    console.log(weeklyPass + "strd");
    break;

  case "sunday":
    console.log(weeklyPass + "snd");
    break;

  default:
    console.log("");
}
```

The error that I get is only that it it not up to the required standards, but I cannot figure out how I could do things differently.

Comment: `update the value of currentPass` You're not updating `currentPass` at all

Comment: I have tried to do that by making it equal to the switch statement, but that doesn t seem to work

Answer (score -1):

```js
// i don't know what the 'required standards' are, but we use the switch statement
// to perform different actions for different conditions.
// here regardless of the weekday we perform the exact same action to generate the password,
// add the consonants of the weekDay to the weeklyPass
// so why use switch? all we have to do is find a way to reduce the string of a weekday to its consonants
const currentPass = (weeklyPass, weekDay) => weeklyPass + weekDay.match(/[^aeiouy]/g).join('');
console.log(currentPass('darlene', 'monday'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Its seems almost correct just need to update the value of the currentPass...

```js
var weeklyPass = 'darlene';
var weekDay = 'friday';
var currentPass;




switch (weekDay){
    case 'friday':
        (currentPass = weeklyPass + 'frd');
        break;
 }
 
 console.log(currentPass);

//Just need to feel the rest of the week days .
```

...